# How to improve update query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why update query takes too much time?

table1

```
Id      table2Id(Unique key)    
101        201
102        205
```

table2

```
Id    table1Id Name bool
201      101  'A'    0
202      101  'B'    0
203      101  'C'    0
205      102  'A'    0
206      102  'B'    0
```

Table 1 will contain only one table2 Id(one to one). But table2 contain multiple table1 id(one(table2) to many(table1))

```
update table 2 set bool=1
where Id( select t2.Id from table2 join table1 on t2.Id(PKey)=t1.table2Id(PKey) and t2.Name='A')
```

This query takes time to update around 6mins. If I run inner select query within  2sec getting results.

If I change join on condition like **t1.Id=t2.table1Id** then update query executes within 5sec.

Any idea why?

Comment: What kind of database? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: sql server  am using

Comment: Is that your correct update query??

Comment: I assume you meant to say "table2Id is unique in table1 (one-to-one)".

Comment: Your query is not accurate and to me (at least) the intention is unclear.  For instance, what is being `set`?

Comment: In both table Id is Primary key column and t1.table2Id is unique key..
If t1.table2Id=t2.Id works fine and executing in 6mins(row count approx 800). but same without update select alone executes only in  5sec. Same like If I change to t1.Id=t2.table1Id it executes only 5mins.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query which works well for you. However, this is not valid `SQL` update query in terms of any other DBMS Product.

```
update table 2 set 
where Id( select t2.Id from table2 join table1 on t2.Id(PKey)=t1.table2Id(PKey))
```

So, let me correct you with SQL update quert with above

```
UPDATE t1 SET table2Id = t2.Id -- Whaterver going to update
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t2.Id = t1.Id -- whatever input parameter you have for logical/physical join operation
```

Now, in terms of performance the above is perform well if table1(Id) has primary key constraint or index.

Comment: In both table Id is Primary key column and t1.table2Id is unique key.. If t1.table2Id=t2.Id works fine and executing in 6mins(row count approx 800). but same without update select alone executes only in 5sec. Same like If I change to t1.Id=t2.table1Id it executes only 5mins.